# KDTree return distances in all dimensions

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, vector, scipy, distance

Using `scipy.spatial.KDTree()` in Python returns two arrays: 1.The distance to the nearest point in a list of vectors, 2. The index of the closest vector in the list.

However the distances returned are the Euclidean distances. Is there a way to return the individual components that give the Euclidean distance?

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

a = np.round(np.random.uniform(0,10,(4,2)))

a
Out[171]: 
array([[2., 8.],
       [8., 1.],
       [6., 9.],
       [3., 6.]])

f_test = np.array([8.,1.1])

tree = spatial.KDTree(a)
distances, indices = tree.query(f_test)

distances
Out[169]: 0.10000000000000009

indices
Out[170]: 1
```

Here the output of `distances` I would like is `[0.,0.1]` i.e. the distance of `f_test` to the nearest vector in `a` but in an elementwise fashion.

NOTE:
This is a simple example where I have only compared one vector to a 2D array of vectors but in reality I would like to return the minimum full-vector distances of a new `f_test` (which is a 2D array of test vectors) to the original array `a`. Otherwise this would be a simple problem of finding the smallest component after subtracting `f_test` from `a`.

eg. if:

```
f_test = np.array([[8.,1.1],[6.,9.2]])
```

Then I would  like to return `distances` as `np.array([[0.,0.1],[0.,0.2]])`

`KDTree` allows the fast calculation of minimum distances for an array of vectors with no looping hence why I'm using it as an example here.

Link to `KDTree` docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html